# HTML Input Pattern Comma and Letters

Tags: html, design-patterns, input, textarea

What is the correct pattern for a text input to only allow uppercase letters, lowercase letters, and commas?

I know that this is correct for the letters:

```
pattern="[a-zA-Z]"
```

but I dont know how to allow commas.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: uhm ... just add `,` ? ( like `[a-zA-Z,]` )

Comment: @KarelG Something else must be wrong then because that still wont work. https://jsfiddle.net/u838f3qL/2/

Comment: Why do you want to add commas? Which application is this for (CSV)?

Comment: @Syfer its for a stock market script, only accept stock symbols separated by commas.

Comment: SQL? Your tags dont say that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer:

```
pattern="^[a-zA-Z,]*$"
```

A couple of comment:

- * means zero or more characters which means this patter will allow empty fields as well. If you want to guarantee that it will contain at least one character, use + instead of *.
- ^ means beginning of the string and $ is the end. If you don't use them then something like this would be possible "*!#123asdSDADS,,,21312312*(2"

Comment: The second bullet is not true. It's not required in this situation. You can leave it out when you use that input attribute. The OP wasn't clear in his question but `[a-zA-Z,]*` is enough.